# Добавить путь изображения из ассет папки в массив джава

Tags: java, android, android-assets

Здравствуйте извините если вопрос покажется глупым но я хочу взять свои изображения из ассет папки и их пут добавить в массив потом как константа вызвать с разных активити я до этого сделал так что они брались и drawable папки все работала а аудио из папка raw тоже самое все работает но я уже до делал все но хочу что бы у меня все было по палочкам акуратно и хотел бы все изображения которые не используется программой находились в ассет папке и аудио в сортированном виде по папкам в ассет папке вот пример то что я смог сделать

```
public static InputStream[] CART_IMAGES;
{
    try {
        CART_IMAGES= new InputStream[]{
                    assetManager.open("cart/cart_1.png"), assetManager.open("cart/cart_6.png"),
                    assetManager.open("cart/cart_2.png"), assetManager.open("cart/cart_7.png"),
                    assetManager.open("cart/cart_3.png"), assetManager.open("cart/cart_8.png"),
                    assetManager.open("cart/cart_4.png"), assetManager.open("cart/cart_9.png"),
                    assetManager.open("cart/cart_5.png"), assetManager.open("cart/cart_10.png")
            };
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

здесь он вызывает аудио и изображения setImageResource принимает только int а не inputStream как это можно еще реализовать уже как вот 3 дня пытаюсь до этого хотел даже написать жсон файл и оттуда вызавать но не знаю как прописать путь изображения с ассет папки в жсон файл ах да если что-то написал не понятно извините у меня немножко плохо с русским спасибо заранее

```
    cartImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cartImage);

    detector = new SwipeManager(this, this);

    cartImage.setImageResource(CART_IMAGES[position]);

    cartImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playAudio(Constants.CART_SOUND[position]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо все сделал с помощью пикассо и немножко изменил код все работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чувак, assets и resources как бы разные вещи)

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream iStream = assetManager.open("cart/cart_1.png");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Да я в курсе но есть ли способы какие то что бы был и код и ресурсные папки выглядели красиво